# React native, extracting data from an object

Tags: sql, json, object, react-native, tostring

I have this method which queries the database. The query is working and I would like to use the results from the query to do other stuff with it. Problem is, I can't use the data because it is in an object file.

```
 EventListener() {
      this.store.db.executeSql('SELECT id, event FROM eventi WHERE status = "new"', null,
      (resultset) => {
        console.log(resultset)
        alert(resultset)
      }, this.NewEventerror)
  }
```

How to get it out? I've tried `JSON.stringify(resultset)`, but the alert and the `console.log` doesn't pop. 
Any ideas?

Comment: can you attach an example of how the `resultset` object looks?

Comment: and your `alert` syntax is not correct, here you can see how you should use it: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/alert.html

Comment: @Cherniv unortunately I have no way of finding out how it looks like :/

Comment: did you try `JSON.parse(resultset)` ?

Comment: Running on android emulator, chrome debugger is reporting `warning - exception while invoking a callback: {}` when using that.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in the meantime:

```
EventListener() {
      this.store.db.executeSql('SELECT id, event, vrijeme, status FROM eventi WHERE status = "new"', null,
      (resultset) => {
        const events
        events.push(resultset.rows.item())
        }
      }, this.NewEventerror)
```

established an `events` variable and pushed the `resultset` in it, then accessed the object elements with `events.objectelement`

Comment: can you explain more specifically for example where does the 'events' object come from? I m asking cause I working on this issue.

Comment: 'events' object is declared (created) inside the callback function (`const events`)